# Tkinter StringVar

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi folks I'm trying to add a function that goes up by 0.2 everytime i click on the button.
I was able to do it with a IntVar (1, 2, 3 ...) but now I'm just to dumb for that.
It should do both, the step by 1, 2, 3 etc and the 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 etc.

````
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.minsize("300", "200")
root.maxsize("400", "300")
root.title("Test")


counter = tkinter.IntVar()
fish = tkinter.StringVar()
fished = 0


def onClick(event=None):
    fish.set(str(fished + 0.2))
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)
    print(counter.get())
    num1 = counter.get() * 0.2
    print(num1)


messagevar = Message(root, textvariable = fish)
messagevar.config(bg="lightgreen")
messagevar.pack()

tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=counter).pack()
tkinter.Button(root, text="increase", command=onClick, fg="black", bg = "white").pack()



root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: `fished + 0.2` produces exactly the same value each time, because nothing in your code changes `fished`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integers don't store decimal places by definition; you have to use a float type. You could use `DoubleVar()` instead of `IntVar()`. However, you could just use a variable as you are attempting to do.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.minsize("300", "200")
root.maxsize("400", "300")
root.title("Test")


counter = tkinter.DoubleVar()
fish = tkinter.StringVar()
fished = 0


def onClick(event=None):
    global fished
    fished += 0.2  # equivalent to fished = fished + 0.2
    fish.set(str(fished))
    counter.set(counter.get() + 0.2)
    print(counter.get())


messagevar = Message(root, textvariable = fish)
messagevar.config(bg="lightgreen")
messagevar.pack()

tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=counter).pack()
tkinter.Button(root, text="increase", command=onClick, fg="black", bg = "white").pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the string counter the same way as you do with the integer counter:

```py
import tkinter


def on_click():
    fish.set(f'{float(fish.get()) + 0.2:.1f}')
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

counter = tkinter.IntVar()
fish = tkinter.StringVar(value='0')

message_var = tkinter.Message(root, textvariable=fish, bg="lightgreen")
message_var.pack()

tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=counter).pack()
tkinter.Button(root, text="increase", command=on_click, fg="black", bg="white").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Just get the value, convert it to a float, add the .2, also format it because of the float precision.

Also you can configure the background when initializing the object and your given code wouldn't actually run because name `tkinter` isn't defined.

Additionally:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations.